# $http request from AngularJS to Django

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to send `GET` request to Django. In the script:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'GET', 
    url: 'response/',
    data: 'test=data',
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log(data);
});
```

In the `view` `response()` function, if I try

```
def response(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

I will get `500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`. If I try

```
def response(request):
    data = request.body
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

the returned data is empty. I wonder what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

do it like this:

```
$http({ 
  method: 'GET', 
  url: 'response/',
  data: $.param({
    'test': 'data
  })
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
  console.log(data);
});
```

and use request.GET -

```
def response(request):
    data = request.GET.get('test')
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code like this.

```
$http({ 
   method: 'GET', url: '../../load/', 
   data: {'test': 'Nath'}, 
   header: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function (data) {
   var ck = data.data;
 }, function(response) { console.log("failed to load data."); });
```

views will be

```
def response(request):
    data = request.GET.get('test')
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

it worked..